# VSCode extension development: How can I get the definition file of a type?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing a VSCode C++ extension. I would add an include instruction to the current file (which uses the type).
It is like an import instruction in JS.
How can I get the file path of the file where the type is defined?
Is there a way to get the file of goToTypeDefinition or goToDefinition?

Comment: what do you mean with `Type` of the file. If you give an example with file names would really help

Answer (score 0):

you can get the path of the current file with

```
vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri
```

Comment: I know that. That's not what I asked.